# Is there an SQL command to select all of a query or one of a query if condition true?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table full of clothes, and their description.
 I would like to have a query that returns every value where the [Jacket Size] is XXL, if the [Shop] has that [Color] only in XXL, but get every size of that [Color] group if XXL is missing.
 My Database looks like this (with more shops):

```
|      ID      |      Shop      |      Jacket Size      |      Jacket Color      |      Season      |      Washing compatible      |      In storage      |      Warrantee      |      Gender|
|--------------|-----------------|----------------------|------------------------|------------------|------------------------------|----------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|      1      |      Walmart      |      XS      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      F|
|      2      |      Walmart      |      XL      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      M|
|      3      |      Walmart      |      XXL      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      M|
|      4      |      Walmart      |      XS      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      5      |      Walmart      |      S      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      6      |      Walmart      |      XXL      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      7      |      Walmart      |      XS      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      8      |      Walmart      |      S      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      9      |      Walmart      |      XS      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      10      |      Walmart      |      S      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      11      |      Walmart      |      M      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      12      |      Walmart      |      L      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      13      |      Walmart      |      XL      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      14      |      Walmart      |      L      |      Black      |      Spring/Autumn      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      15      |      Walmart      |      XL      |      Black      |      Spring/Autumn      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      16      |      Walmart      |      XXL      |      Black      |      Spring/Autumn      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      17      |      Decathlon      |      XS      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      F|
|      18      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      F|
|      19      |      Decathlon      |      XS      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      20      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      21      |      Decathlon      |      M      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      22      |      Decathlon      |      L      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      23      |      Decathlon      |      XL      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      24      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      25      |      Decathlon      |      M      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      26      |      Decathlon      |      L      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      27      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      28      |      Decathlon      |      M      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      29      |      Decathlon      |      L      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      30      |      Decathlon      |      XL      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      31      |      Decathlon      |      XXL      |      Black      |      Spring/Autumn      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
```

I would like to get only the data like this:

```
|      Id      |      Shop      |      Jacket Size      |      Jacket Color      |      Season      |      Washing compatible      |      In storage      |      Warrantee      |      Gender|
|--------------|-----------------|----------------------|------------------------|------------------|------------------------------|----------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|      3      |      Walmart      |      XXL      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      M|
|      6      |      Walmart      |      XXL      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      7      |      Walmart      |      XS      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      8      |      Walmart      |      S      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      9      |      Walmart      |      XS      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      10      |      Walmart      |      S      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      11      |      Walmart      |      M      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      12      |      Walmart      |      L      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      13      |      Walmart      |      XL      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      16      |      Walmart      |      XXL      |      Black      |      Spring/Autumn      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      17      |      Decathlon      |      XS      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      F|
|      18      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      Red      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      2m      |      F|
|      19      |      Decathlon      |      XS      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      20      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      21      |      Decathlon      |      M      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      22      |      Decathlon      |      L      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      23      |      Decathlon      |      XL      |      Green      |      Spring/Autumn      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      24      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      25      |      Decathlon      |      M      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      26      |      Decathlon      |      L      |      Blue      |      Winter      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      27      |      Decathlon      |      S      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      28      |      Decathlon      |      M      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      F|
|      29      |      Decathlon      |      L      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      30      |      Decathlon      |      XL      |      White      |      Winter      |      Yes      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
|      31      |      Decathlon      |      XXL      |      Black      |      Spring/Autumn      |      No      |      Yes      |      1y      |      M|
```

Thanks in advance.

//Mr. Admin, I clarified the problem, and I got a solution to it, what was the problem?

Comment: Use a [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause

Comment: What should be returned if you have the color in XXL and S for example?

Comment: @Gnqz Only XXL, if XXL is available. If S, M, L and XXL are all available, then the XXL is the only one that should come back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make union of two selects just as you explained it.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE JacketSize = 'XXL'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM YourTable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * FROM YourTable b
  WHERE b.JacketSize = 'XXL' 
    AND a.Color = b.Color
    AND a.Shop = b.Shop
)
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c43ac5/1)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as intended. Is it even possible to learn this power if I am only a human?